# Название ee-символа в LaTex

Tags: latex

Как называется данный ee-символ? Рисую электрическую схему, но этот символ в гугле найти не могу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, что Вы называете *ee-символ*. И что из электрических компонентов это может означать? Коаксиальный провод? И Вы уверены, что это отдельный символ, а не нарисованный из нескольких?

Comment: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это очень интересный документ (всегда его смотрю в первую очередь в поисках нужных символов), но он большой. Укажите хотя бы страницу, где нашли сие чудо. Я там такого символа с первого раза не нашел. И со второго раза - тоже :-).

Comment: @Vladimir, я и не искал. комментарий выше был как бы предложением автору вопроса самому поискать.

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html